# Json, Rails Geocoder and Gmaps for Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, gmaps4rails, rails-geocoder

With Ruby Geocoder I am able to convert address to latitude and longitude and then display it with google static map. However, when trying to use gmap for rails I am getting a blank container.

### view - html.erb Static Map

```
    <%= image_tag "http://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?size=450x300&sensor=false&zoom=16&markers=#{@location.latitude}%2C#{@location.longitude}" %>
```

When trying to replace the static map with gmaps4rails I add the following

```
    <%= yield :scripts %> 
    <%= gmaps4rails(@json) %>
```

I also added the necessities in my controller and model. An empty container displays and I feel like it's just not reading the data. I played around with some things I read, but I may not be understanding. Can someone help enlighten me?

Comment: Can you show me a controller code? In particular, `index` and `show` actions

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try with replace

this

```
<%= yield :scripts %> 
<%= gmaps4rails(@json) %>
```

with

```
<%= gmaps4rails(@json) %>
<%= yield :scripts %>
```

I also faced same issue before. Solution is put `<%= yield :scripts %>` at the last line of your file.

Thanks.

Comment: This is an old post and was solved, but thanks. I should've had put solution, but I dont remember what it was